# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on 120Gb ssd and 500Gb hdd partitioning [ CLOSED ]

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am running win 8.1 on my 500gb hdd. just bought a ssd. want to move to ubuntu 16.04 by installing it to the ssd.

I don't have any 2nd slot for hdd. so i thought of moving my hdd to the optical drive slot and put the ssd in the primary slot.

I've done the bootable usb for ubuntu ready. I don't care about the hdd for formatting. but as it will be on the optical drive slot,, I'm confused what to do on the BIOS.

Basically my question is how will I walk through the whole process[like changing BIOS settings, formatting hdd, partitioning ssd etc..]
I will be thankful if you help me with detailed explanation. 
Thnx! :D

Re: I've got 2gb ram. Planning to add a 4gb after some time.
My Laptop Model: Asus X55C-SX078D

Comment: What is the make and model number of your computer?

Comment: Asus X55C-SX078D

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... L.D.James

Comment: No problem about the time in responding.  Just respond when it's convenient.  I would like to suggest that you remove the reference to `bios` from the title of your question.  It's distracting from your real question, which I believe, how to install Ubuntu on the fresh drive.  I gave the answer to how to do this below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have to format your new `ssd`drive.  If you'll be installing ubuntu on that drive, the formatting and other processes for using it is done automatically during the install process.  Just select that drive to install Ubuntu.  When selecting the drive, you should easily know which drive by looking at the size.

**Checking and changing which drive boots (the boot order)**

To check or set which of your drives will be the primary one for boot, you would do this in the bios.  You can get to the bios with:

When you first turn on a computer you should see a key to hit to enter the bios.  For the `Asus` the key is the <kbd>DEL</kbd> key.

Comment: As I have windows on the c drive of the hdd will it be ok ok if i just format the c drive and create it again? or will i have to format the whole hdd?

Comment: As for the ssd I found some sites are telling not to create swap on the ssd...

Comment: If you have any data you consider important backed up from your `c drive`, you can choose that for installing Ubuntu only, if that is what you want to do.  You don't have to format or partition it.  Just choose that drive for the install.  Ubuntu's install will automatically erase the whole drive and perform the process as if it were a new drive.  Or you can use `gparted` to organize the `C drive`... shrinking a partition to make space and creating a new partition for Ubuntu.

Comment: Thnx! :D By the way what about the swap partition on ssd?

Comment: @If the `ssd` drive is the only drive I would suggest a `swap` partition.  Because of how inexpensive ram is today, I would also suggest trying ensure that you have enough ram in your system, depending on your use, to minimize running out of ram.  The problem comes when you run out of ram and the system uses the swap for ram.  If you have two drives, put the swap partition on your cheaper drive instead .  By the way, I strongly suggest that you remove the `changing bios settings`  from your topic.

Comment: You will need an EFI partition on the SSD too if you are making it the boot device.  The installer will ignore any "location" you enter and put the Ubuntu bootloaders onto the hdd's EFI.  Just copy them over to the SDD's EFI.

Comment: alri8. thnx guys :D

Comment: SO ATLAST: PUT "/" OR ROOT ON SSD , SWAP ON HDD AND COPY EFI TO SSD. RI8?